# Strange issue PHP session inside condition

Tags: php, session, conditional-statements

I have this code:

```
session_start();

$i = 'NO';

if ( $_GET['page'] != 'login' ) {

    $_SESSION['redirect'] = 'my-account';

    $i = 'YES';

}
```

The logic says:

allways **$_GET['page'] != "login"**, the block inside IF condition will be skipped...

In a URL like this: `www.example.com/?page=login`

The first time is OK, `$_SESSION['redirect']` has no value

if I reload the page, `$i` still has the value **"NO"** (OK)
but `$_SESSION['redirect']` now contains the value **"my-account"**

Currently, this code is everything that is written on my test url

And a strange thing more:

Chrome / Firefox (Windows) and Chrome (Mac) exhibit this behavior

Firefox (Mac) effectively ignores the block

how can it be possible?

Comment: $i is *not* stored in the session. the session only covers the array `$_SESSION` - everything you want to persist, you have to store in there.

Comment: `SESSION` is super global variable and it's scope remains till it's not destroyed, but `$i = 'YES'` is variable whose scope is lost after  condition executed. So at the time of page refresh `$i` again become `NO`

Comment: First clue, but in the network inspector, when you request a page, I think the browser always process another request to get the favicon ?

Comment: $i is only for print on screen and see if really the block is jumped, the question is, how can it be possible that the session variable has a value if the block should skip?

Comment: @armate1hernan  as i said that till you are not going to destroy or cange session value it will hold the older value. first time your if block executes and session maintained. So till you not destroy or change that,older value will remain.

Comment: @armate1hernan  simple to understand when you login to a system, a session created for you and in log-out that session destroyed. On each other pages you use that session

Comment: This simplified code runs on all pages of the system, but the problem appeared when I tried it on **/index.php?page=login** multiple times with a newly created session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
<?php
session_start();

$i = 'NO';
$page = $_GET['page'];
if ( isset($page) ) {
    if ($page != 'login') {
        $_SESSION['redirect'] = 'my-account';
        $i = 'YES';
    } else {
        $_SESSION['redirect'] = '';
    }
}

echo $i;
echo $_SESSION['redirect'];
?>
```

before trying it, clear the session variable

Comment: Sure. @armate1hernan

Answer (score 1):

So, your SESSION is getting set even though you think it shouldn't? 
Your page is probably getting called anyway - either you have a redirect to it or an auto include, and the browser is then calling it when you yourself call the page because it's trying to load "favicon.ico".

Comment: how could avoid in this same code that takes into account the favicon request for testing, I think you are right and this was the problem

Comment: If you want to avoid it you should make your auto include or redirect not include your php file always, but do it for *.php. You could also in your php file check $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] to see if it has favicon.ico and then exit.